# Cloudstack missing templates

Tags: cloud, cloudstack

I have installed several templates in cloudstack and I can see them in TEMPLATES module of management. But when I try to add an instance all the templates are missing. Did anyone experienced the same issue in the past?

Thank you

---Edited---

Looks like it is because the system KVM is unable to start. I tried to load the KVM manually and I get the following errors:

> char device redirected to /dev/pts/2 TUNGETIFF ioctl() failed: Bad
>
> file descriptor TUNSETOFFLOAD ioctl() failed: Bad file descriptor
>
> TUNGETIFF ioctl() failed: Bad file descriptor TUNSETOFFLOAD ioctl()
>
> failed: Bad file descriptor TUNGETIFF ioctl() failed: Bad file
>
> descriptor TUNSETOFFLOAD ioctl() failed: Bad file descriptor

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the templates are actually installed? If you click on them in the templates section what is the status?

Although the templates have been created, it does not mean they have been installed, this tricked me for a while.

Also, are the templates available for the project, domain and user that you are using to try and create a VM?

Comment: If I click on template in the templates section I can see the status: Download Complete and Ready:Yes

Yes the templates are available for domain. 

@boburob: how did you solve your problem? how did you realize that the template was not installed although it was created?

Thank you

Comment: Silly question but have you checked all 3 tabs of the template selection screen? Could help making the template public if it is not already

Comment: Also if it says Complete and Ready it should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to to post on the user mailing list. The mailing list is read and responded to regularly by consultants, users, and developers.

Subscribe by sending an email to `cloudstack-users-subscribe@incubator.apache.org`

Next, send an email explaining the problem to cloudstack-users@incubator.apache.org

There have been some recent issues with KVM, so you might also check the mailing list archive, which is at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cloudstack-users/

I use google to search the list.  E.g. google `site:http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cloudstack-users/ kvm`

Answer (score 0):

are you using local storage for system VMs ?

Can you check if your system VMs are up and running ?

- If ssvm are stuck in stopping state then disable the zone.

  1. Clear your NFS directory i.e (secondary storage)
  2. Remove system vms from cloudstack UI as well as `/var/lib/libvirt/images`.
  3. Then register the system VM template for kvm and check template status.
  4. After that enable the zone and check if cloudstack is able to create ssvm properly.

Once ssvm is created, remaining templates will be downloaded and you should be able to create VMs.